# jQuery- are ajax responses received in order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

If I have something like:

```
var result;

var searchFunction = function(query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '..',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'query': query
        },
        success: function(result) {
            r = result
        }
    });
};
```

will `r` always end up to be the result from the last `searchFunction(query)` call?

For example, lets say I do this:

```
searchFunction('query1'); // this one takes 3 seconds to return because of internet delay
searchFunction('query2'); // this one takes 1 seconds to return because of less internet delay
```

will my `r` be `'result1'` or `'result2'`?

Since it is supposed to be an async (AJAX), I'd expect `r = 'result1'`, but from some tests I did, I got `r = 'result2'`.

What really happens?

Comment: one way to do it is to abort the previous request before sending a new request...

Comment: Actually I think I know how to solve that kind of concurrency problem, I just wanted to know what really happens in this specific web case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asynchronous Ajax calls can return in ANY order.  You cannot rely on the order.  You can only reliably use the result of an ajax call in the completion handler for THAT particular Ajax call or in some function you call and pass the result to from the completion handler.

You absolutely do NOT want to be putting ajax results into global variables and then try to use them from there.  That is a recipe for a timing disaster and is never a good way to code it.

If you want to coordinate the results of multiple ajax calls, you can do a bunch of custom coding yourself to keep track of results in order or you can use a third party library like Async or promises.

---

If the actual problem you're trying to solve is some sort of incremental search where you may have multiple requests in flight at the same time and you don't want to process a request that is older than something you've already received, then you need to create a system such that keeps track of sequencing so you know when to ignore a response.  There are a number of ways to approach that:

1. You can abort any previous request each time you send a new one.
2. You can tag each request with a monotonically increasing number and then keep track of the highest response number you've processed so far and ignore any with lower numbers.

FYI, if your server processes each request synchronously (thus it starts on the first one that arrives and isn't available to process any other request until that first one is done) and can only process one request at a time, then it may only return results in FIFO order, regardless of how long each request takes.  If, on the other hand, your request processing was asynchronous or your server could process multiple requests at a time, then the request with the shortest execution time will return first.

Comment: From http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ "The first letter in Ajax stands for "asynchronous," meaning that the operation occurs in parallel and the order of completion is not guaranteed."

Comment: I actually solved the "problem" by setting a global index variable and incrementing it in every request, then I'd copy it to a local variable in the function block so that I could compare it in the success block (similar, but not as elegant, as your second solution). But maybe I wasn't clear, my question was not whether or not the concurrency problem exists and how to solve it, my question was "does this concurrency problem exists?", because I can't seem to reproduce it. When I did those manually 2 requests and forced those delays in the server, the result1 always returned before the result2.

Comment: Although I'd also very much like to know how to implement your two solutions.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz - you can see the issue reproduced here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/j11w8sbq/ - responses come back in the opposite order they were sent.  Some of the issue depends upon the implementation in the server.  If the server only serves one request at a time synchronously, then it will probably return results in the order requested.  But, in a multi-request server or in an async architecture like node, the first request done is the first one returned.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, because I think it might be due to the fact I have only one dyno in Heroku, so probably sync server, but please add this last comment to your answer.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz - info about server-side request processing added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is `r` that you are setting? No matter what, you can't expect AJAX (asynchronous by definition) to happen in any sort of order. If you are going to be making multiple calls, and want to store all of the responses, you will want to do something like:

```
var resultSet = [];

var searchFunction = function(query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '..',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'query': query
        },
        success: function(result) {
            resultSet.push(result);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Actually r was just my way of simplifying it, what I actually do is repopulate a table with that result. Also I know I shouldn't expect any order in the responses, but why are they returning in the same order I'm sending? Even with different delays...

Answer (score 0):

AJAX responses will be processed in the order that the responses arrive. The order that they're sent is irrelevant. I've modified your code to log the response, you can see in the Javascript console that the fast query is processed first.

```
var searchFunction = function(query, delay) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            json: JSON.stringify(query),
            delay: delay
        },
        success: function(r) {
            console.log(r);
        }
    });
};

searchFunction('query1', 3);
searchFunction('query2', 1);
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/6f69wa60/6/)

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what that '/echo/json/' is (sorry for my ignorance), but in my real server that is not what happens (The delay is actually in the server due to database access).

Comment: `/echo/json/` is an AJAX server on jsfiddle that's used for testing AJAX. On your real application, maybe something in the database is serializing the two queries, so the fast query is waiting for the slow query to finish.